# Spark Streaming: StreamingContext doesn't read data files

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I'm new in Spark Streaming and I'm trying to getting started with it using Spark-shell.
Assuming I have a directory called "dataTest" placed in the root directory of spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4.

The simple code that I want to test in the shell is (after typing $.\bin\spark-shell):

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val data = ssc.textFileStream("dataTest")
println("Nb lines is equal to= "+data.count())
data.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) => println(rdd.count()) }
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

And then, I copy some files in the directory "dataTest" (and also I tried to rename some existing files in this directory).

But unfortunately I did not get what I want (i.e, I didn't get any outpout, so it seems like ssc.textFileStream doesn't work correctly), just some things like:

```
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1421346766000 ms
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1421346766000 ms
.0 from job set of time 1421346766000 ms
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: foreachRDD at <console>:20
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 69 finished: foreachRDD at <console>:20
, took 0,000021 s
0
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1421346766000 ms
.0 from job set of time 1421346766000 ms
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO MappedRDD: Removing RDD 137 from persistence list
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0,005 s for time 1421346766000
ms (execution: 0,002 s)
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 137
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO UnionRDD: Removing RDD 78 from persistence list
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 78
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO FileInputDStream: Cleared 1 old files that were older tha
n 1421346706000 ms: 1421346704000 ms
15/01/15 19:32:46 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
```

Answer (score 4):

Copy file/document Using command line or save as the file/document to the directory work for me.
When you normally copy(by IDE) this can't effect the modified date as streaming context monitor modified date.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try *moving* text files from another directory into the directory that is being monitored? For file stream to work, you are atomically put the files into the monitored directory, so that as soon as the files becomes visible in the listings, Spark can read all the data in the file (which may not be the case if you are copying files into the directory).

This is well documented in the Basic sources subsection in the [programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers)

Comment: I tried moving, renaming text files but sadly I don't get any output !! does it work for you ?

Comment: I had to also make sure that the format is correct - I made the error of saving my text files in .txt.gz format which didn't work. once I saved it as plain text it worked

Answer (score 1):

I have also struggled with the same issue and for me the solution was that *while* the streaming is on running, I edit and save the file that I want to use as input stream. I then directly move the input file to the streaming directory, also while the streaming is still on.

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me

```
class StreamingData extends Serializable {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Application").setMaster("local[2]")
    //val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
    val input = ssc.textFileStream("file:///C:/Users/M1026352/Desktop/Spark/StreamInput")
    val lines = input.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val words = lines.map(word => (word, 1))
    val counts = words.reduceByKey(_ + _)
    counts.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

Just Need to keep the text file in Unix format
If you open the file in notepad++ go to
settings->Preferences->New Document->Unix/OSX
Then changes the file name to get it picked by Scala.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495776/5196927

Refer above link.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should generally work, however the problem may be that it is recommended to do Spark Streaming as a standalone application rather than in spark-shell.

I ran this as a standalone application (on other streaming data) and it worked.

data.count() gives you how many elements are in each RDD of the DStream, which is the same as what you are counting in your foreachRDD().

Comment: What kind of streaming data you have tested ? does it work with text file exististing on your disc ? thanks for replying

Comment: I tested with a twitter stream previously. Today I tested with a file using textFileStream as you have in your example. I was not able to get this to work using the spark-shell on my macbook. I decided to try on an nfs filesystem, in case macbook filesystem is not compatible with hdfs. I still used spark-shell with a local master. I increased the batch size from 2 to 10, to make it easier to see the spewed log lines. The code worked on nfs, as long as I 'mv' the file from another directory in same filesystem (not 'cp'). mv from same directory did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing almost the same thing (as a standalone app on a Windows 8 laptop) and for me this works fine however I have the "dataTest" folder located as a sub folder of "bin". Maybe try that?

Comment: Better you can post these type of reply in comment section

Answer (score 0):

I just use your code in the shell ,it works fine. When I put some files to the directory(HDFS),I got the output log like this:

```
15/07/23 10:46:36 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 9 ms
15/07/23 10:46:36 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1437619596000 ms:
hdfs://master:9000/user/jared/input/hadoop-env.sh
15/07/23 10:46:36 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(235504) called with curMem=0, maxMem=280248975
......
15/07/23 10:46:36 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/07/23 10:46:37 INFO rdd.NewHadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://master:9000/user/jared/input/hadoop-env.sh:0+4387
15/07/23 10:46:42 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 107 ms
15/07/23 10:46:42 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1437619598000 ms:

15/07/23 10:46:42 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1437619598000 ms
15/07/23 10:46:42 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 23 ms
15/07/23 10:46:42 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1437619600000 ms:

15/07/23 10:46:42 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1437619600000 ms
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Finding new files took 42 ms
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: New files at time 1437619602000 ms:
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO scheduler.JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1437619602000 ms
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1830 bytes result sent to driver
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 6098 ms on localhost (1/1)
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (foreachRDD at <console>:29) finished in 6.178 s
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/07/23 10:46:43 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 66 finished: foreachRDD at <console>:29, took 6.647137 s
101
```