# WordCount in spark. No Output in part-00000 and part-00001 in spark streaming vs perfect output in spark core

Tags: stream, apache-spark, word-count

Please find the spark core example which gave output and i can see the each word's count where as spark stream does generate empty part files. Please help.

Spark Core Example:

```
val file = sc.textFile("D:\\Spark-Learn\\FirstSparkStream\\logs\\shakespeare.raw")
val words = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.saveAsTextFile("D:\\Spark-Learn\\FirstSparkStream\\output\\output\\")
```

Spark Stream Example:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext("spark://RSrini7:7077","Streaming Job",Seconds(30),"D:\\DevTools\\spark-1.2.0",List("D:\\Spark-Learn\\FirstSparkStream\\target\\scala-2.10\\simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar"))
val logData = ssc.textFileStream("D:\\Spark-Learn\\FirstSparkStream\\logs")
val words = logData.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.saveAsTextFiles("D:\\Spark-Learn\\FirstSparkStream\\output\\output","output")
```

This example, i tested in my windows 8 machine. master and worker started without any issues and after finishes the Job, there is no warning or error in the console.

This is my first question, please let me know if any other information required.

Comment: Just landed to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970729/spark-streaming-streamingcontext-doesnt-read-data-files

Comment: Network Word Count works:) https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/NetworkWordCount.scala